# send and get requests to server only via front-end of electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a web application which communicates with Nodejs server and sometimes with PHP code via ajax and it works fine.

Now since I'm completely new to electron I need to know if it's possible to only wrap the whole html, javascript and css files of my web app with electron, and without any touch to my code still be able to communicate with server (communicating with Node server and PHP files via ajax).

So for instance let's say I have this piece of code in javascript file of my application and I want to send a POST request to preload.php file in the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../preload.php',
    data: {id: "testdata", directories: directories},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('result is get from server');
    },
});
```

If I put above code in front-end of the electron app, does this still work in windows and macOS apps?

Comment: Usually the main issue is CORS, but since you seem to imply that the server is yours, you can enable it and you should probably be fine.

Comment: Ok.. thanks for the information... I'll use htttps server and yes the server which is running nodejs is mine...But one last question: do you know if the same scnario is ok with apache cordova or other javascript based frameworks for android ?